# How to handle Socket error 10053 in SOAPServerwithINDYVCL in Delphi XE

Tags: soap, indy

I have created a SOAPServerwithINDYVCL in Delphi XE. When a clients gets disconnected from server due to any reason like timeout at client side or net connection dropped.
I am getting error at server side as Socket Error 10053 - software caused connection abort.

this error popsup and blocking my thread of server.

I also checked this withe the demo of SOAPDMServerIndy. Here also if i start server, connect client and before server responds disconnect the client I get socket error.

Anyone knows how to handle this exception?

Comment: Do you see the popup only when running in the debugger? Or do you see it when running outside of the debugger?  If only inside, then that is normal behavior, since the debugger sees exceptions before the app does. Just dismiss the popup and continue, or tell the debugger to ignore that type of exception. But if you are seeing the popup when running outside the debugger, then please show your actual server code, because Indy servers are multi-threaded and thus there should not be any popup unless you are doing something wrong in your code.

Comment: Error occurs when application is running outside debugger mode. 
I have found the same error in the demos of SOAP provided by INDY. In the demo of EchoService 
Changes in server -I have added sleep of 1000 in file EchoServiceImpl.pas-> function TEchoService.echoSoapStructArray 
Changes in client - I have added HTTPRIO1.HTTPWebNode.ConnectTimeout := 20; HTTPRIO1.HTTPWebNode.SendTimeout := 20; HTTPRIO1.HTTPWebNode.ReceiveTimeout := 20; in file ClientForm_U.pas Here we will have the same error at server side which I mentioned above. This error occurs when client disconnects by any reason

Comment: Indy itself does not implement SOAP, and the [open source IndySoap project](http://www.indyproject.org/SOAP/) that supports (but does not rely on) Indy is very old, though I hear that it is in the process of being updated to support the latest Indy.  I don't know what demo you are looking at, but if its server implementation is multi-threaded then there should not be any popup messages, unless the code is either displaying its own popups, or is delegating error handling to the main thread. Can you run the demo in the debugger and look at the call stack when the popups occur?

Comment: How to add zip file to the forum? I am new to this forum so i dont know how to do that

Comment: Edit your question and copy/paste the relevant source code directly into it.

Answer (score 0):

Even at this time this issue still exists. It's because of this code:

```
procedure TWebRequestHandler.HandleException(Sender: TObject);
var
  Handled: Boolean;
  Intf: IWebExceptionHandler;
begin
  Handled := False;
  if ExceptObject is Exception and
    Supports(Sender, IWebExceptionHandler, Intf) then
    try
      Intf.HandleException(Exception(ExceptObject), Handled);
    except
      Handled := True;
      System.SysUtils.ShowException(ExceptObject, ExceptAddr);
    end;
  if (not Handled) then
    System.SysUtils.ShowException(ExceptObject, ExceptAddr);
end;
```

The line `Intf.HandleException(Exception(ExceptObject), Handled)` calls the TCustomWebDispatcher.HandleException procedure. This procedure checks for the existance of a OnException event handler in the TWebModule descendant in your application. If it exists (I would recommend it) the event handler procedure is called with the var argument  'Handled' set to true.

```
procedure TCustomWebDispatcher.HandleException(E: Exception; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  Handled := False;
  if Assigned(FOnException) then
  begin
    Handled := True;
    if Response <> nil then
      Response.StatusCode := 500; { Allow the user to override the StatusCode }
    FOnException(Self, E, Handled);
    if Handled and (Response <> nil) then
      Response.SendResponse;
  end;
  if not Handled then
    if Response <> nil then
    begin
      Response.Content := Format(sInternalApplicationError, [E.Message, Request.PathInfo]);
      if not Response.Sent then
      begin
        Response.StatusCode := 500;
        Response.SendResponse;
      end;
      Handled := True;
    end;
end;
```

When the handler returns there are two situations:

1. Handled is True; The response will be sent which leads to an new Exception. This one will be propagated back to the calling code (the procedure in the first block) so ShowException will be called.
2. Handled is False; `Response <> nil` will evaluate to True so when `Response.Sent` is False the same thing will happen.

I solved this by trying to send the response from the OnException event handler. When it fails an exception is raised. In that case I'm setting the Field 'FResponse' of the read only property 'Response' of my TWebModule's descendant to 'nil'. However, this field is a private field so I used some rtti to be able to access it.

```
procedure TwbmWebBrokerServerModule.UnlinkResponseObject;
begin
  inherited;

  TRTTIContext.Create.GetType(ClassInfo).GetField('FResponse').SetValue(Self, TValue.From(nil));
end;

procedure TwbmWebBrokerServerModule.WebModuleException(Sender: TObject; E: Exception; var Handled: Boolean);
begin
  uVMI_Tools.AppendToLog(E.Message + ' (' + Request.PathInfo + ')');

  if Request.Accept.Contains(CONTENTTYPE_APPLICATION_JSON) then
  begin
    Response.Content := StringToJSON(E.Message);
    Response.ContentType := CONTENTTYPE_APPLICATION_JSON;
  end
  else
    Response.Content := E.Message;

  try
    Response.SendResponse;
  except
    UnlinkResponseObject;
  end;
end;
```

So when an exception occurs while sending the response, the property 'Response' is set to nil so there will be no attempt to send the response again.

There is no need to destroy the response object, assinging nil to it will suffice. It's because the Response object is created within TIdCustomHTTPServer class which just passed it to the TWebModule descendant. (Actually to the TWebModule's parent class TCustomWebDispatcher)